Biblical references in the liturgical text of holy mass
One might claim that catholic liturgy is heavily based on scripture. And in deed, e.g. the liturgy of the mass is full of direct and indirect quotes (or other allusions) from biblical texts.
Some of the more obvious ones are

Behold the Lamb of God, behold him who takes away the sins of the world. (Direct quote from Joh 1,29)

or

Lord, I am not worthy that you should enter under my roof, but only say the word and my soul shall be healed. (Mostly from Math 8,8)

A more indirect one might be

The Lord be with you. -- And with your spirit. (The first part might be found similarly in several verses, such as Ruth 2,4; 1. Chr 22,11. The response might allude to 2. Tim 4,22)

My question is:
Is there an annotated text of the liturgy of the mass (or at least the ordinarium) which gives all these direct and indirect quotes and maybe also the more indirect allusions from scripture?
Since there is substantial overlap in the liturgic texts between the ordinary form of the mass and the traditional latin rite, an annotated text of the vetus ordo might also be helpful.

I'm not aware of such a document, for the catholics or orthodox... I've seen many articles that point things out... but despite existing for so long our churches seem to be missing some basic resources at times. Intrigued to see if anyone has an answer. I added Resource-request, since you're looking for one :)

Just to make it clear: I do not necessarily look for an official church document -- as far as I know there is none. But it might also be the work of some faithful or theologians that have put something together.

@Wyrsa it's because our churches have existed for centuries and centuries before the general public was capable of reading. Telling someone which chapter and verse of scripture a particular line in the liturgy calls back to isn't helpful to someone who can't read.

It's not so difficult to know where all these phrases come from, even for a casual reader of the bible.

@CandidMoe That is exactly my point. Probably someone has put together a document. Somewhere. Probably, I guess.

@jaredad7 The general public has been able to read for a few hundred years now. I am often shocked at how basic things like "the Divine liturgy translated to english for people to read" is a document from the 2000s and not from the 1900s or earlier. Even if the entire design of the church is in such a manner that reading is fully optional, as the Bible is literally depicted in Ikons along the walls and ceilings of the Church building itself...

@Wyrsa yeah, I've been beating this drum for a while, personally. We need to figure out how to evangelize for a literate population. We still haven't figured it out in 2024.

@jaredad7 Yep... I was used to protestants who had like 20 texts even in the 90s... then I converted and suddenly. Nothing, go learn the old fashioned way. Not that it hurt me... but it is suboptimal.
